# How to get resize events in Chrome desktopCapture

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using Chrome's [desktopCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) in an extension and I have an issue that I'm attempting to work around. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I cannot post any source, but the chrome extension itself is commonly available and used on the web.

**Issue**

The issue is with resize / dimension changes that may occur while desktopCapture is capturing / streaming to the server. These changes can often occur seemingly too fast for my client to handle, causing the client application to crash.

**Solution**

I'd like to get some event or notification when the capturing end detects a resize of the area being captured; for instance a window which has been clicked and is being dragged to resize it.

An alternative would be if the `event.data` can be queried for width / height.

**Research**

I've google'd and searched the chrome / webrtc issues; I've come up empty thus far. There really isn't any good implementation information available from what I've found.

Going through the Chromium codebase is not an option for me; I am not a C/C++ developer.

**What I would like from You**

If you have experience with the desktopCapture offering, please share what you know. If you don't have any idea what I'm asking or have nothing constructive to add, please ignore this and move on.

**Commentary**

As of July 17th 2015, it would appear that there is a bug or missing support for resize events in Chromes desktopCapture extension. I will file an enhancement request with them and see where that goes. It probably won't help that "normal" WebRTC streams aren't "expected" to change dimensions during streaming and thus it is not handled.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the captured stream to a video element and listen for the onresize (onsize?) event. Should also work for hidden elements if you don't want to display something at the capturing end.

Comment: Any idea of the best way to do this on the capture-side? I'm not even certain that we can access the captured stream on the capture end.

Comment: only if you attach the stream to a video. In the future. the video tracks getSettings might provide the resolution but AFAIK this has not been implemented

Comment: Attaching to a video element on the publish side yields no resize events in the latest chrome; I think I'll have to throw in the towel at this point as the hooks / support just isn't there yet.

Comment: My Chrome Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit) for reference

Comment: ah, it's onsize -- sorry. alternatively, onloadedmetadata should work. See https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/blob/master/test/test.js#L49-53

Comment: I'll check that out and for resize, I tried both onresize and resize.